# Export website privately from Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a company Google Sheets workbook which ideally I'd like to share internally as HTML; at present it's shared as a .pdf which is OK but imperfect.

To do so, I use the link sheets.google.com/etc/export?format=pdf, and I was wondering if there was an html equivalent?

Note that I do **not** want to use the 'publish' option which does of course create an HTML version, however that is viewable to anyone with the link which I do not want - I want this only to be viewable by specific accounts with which it's been shared.

Answer (score 1):

I came across [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70) that demonstrates how the export request is made, which looks like what you're currently using

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{SpreadsheetId}/export?format=pdf
```

I then found in the **File -> Download** menu that there is an option to download an HTML as a zipped file, and using network inspector they use the "zip" endpoint.

So I took the export link and changed the PDF to zip

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{SpreadsheetId}/export?format=zip
```

And it downloads your workbook in HTML format, stored in a zip file (because it includes css and other resources that may be embedded in the book)

If you're automating the export process you can have it unzipped afterwards.